# JUnit test for complex Java Models

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, composite

i want to learn/know how can i test complex java classes with JUnit.

I have a java project, where i'm reading the content from a properties file 
, then i parse the content of the file to java objects. The properties file has a tree structure, therefore i have implement the Java Model likewise the composite pattern.
[image]

So, when i want to write unit tests for the composite class or for any class of the project, how should i write those tests? How should the test look like? Should it look like this?

```
 @Test
 public void testComposition()
 {
     // Create a object of the Composite class, what you expect after reading
     // from the file
     Composite expectedObject = new Composite();
     ...

     // Call the parser class of the file which returns a composite
     Composite createdObject = PropertiesFileParser.parse(file);

     // and then i have to assert the 2 object with a method from Assert 
     // e.g.
     assertEqual(createdObject, expectedObject);
 }
```

Do i have to create the expected Composite object `expectedObject` "by hand"? Or is there any other method to do things like that?

Are there some coding conventions in writing Junit test cases?

I'm grateful for every helpful answer! (Please excuse my english)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should check each individual method of your object. So, if I were you, I would check a few trivial cases of a tiny model by invoking individual methods of leaf and composite.  For example, I would:

1. Create a composite.
2. Make sure it has no children.
3. Make sure it gracefully refuses to remove a child that it does not own.
4. Add a child.
5. Make sure it has one child.
6. Make sure it still gracefully refuses to remove a child that it does not own.
7. Add one more child.
8. Make sure it has two children.
9. Make sure it gracefully refuses to add a child that it already contains.
10. Remove the first child.
11. Make sure it has one child.
12. Remove the second child.
13. Make sure it has no children.
14. Make sure it gracefully refuses to remove a child that it does not own anymore.

Then, you need to write a few tests that make sure that your object's `equals()` method works absolutely correctly, because later on this method will be invoked a lot by junit's `assertEqual()`.  So, if I were you, I would:

1. Create a single object A.
2. Create a copy of A as B.
3. Make sure A equals B.
4. Create a copy of A as C and change it by a tiny little bit.
5. Make sure A does not equal C.
6. Create a copy of A as D and change it by a tiny little bit.
7. Make sure A does not equal D.
8. Create a copy of A as E and change it by a tiny little bit.
9. Make sure A does not equal E.

...and so on, and so forth, until you are confident that absolutely nothing happens in your `Leaf.equals()` and `Composite.equals()` methods which goes untested.

Then, you should test the basics of tiny hierarchies by hand. So:

1. Create a small hierarchy A. (Just one parent and one child.)
2. Create a small hierarchy B which is identical to A.
3. Make sure A equals B.
4. Create a small hierarchy X which is different from A in a tiny detail.
5. Make sure A does not equal X.
6. Create a small hierarchy Y which is different from A in another tiny detail.
7. Make sure A does not equal Y.
8. Create a small hierarchy Z which is different from A in yet another tiny detail.
9. Make sure A does not equal Z.

Once you have done all of the above, then you can hit the disk.

Hitting the disk is for making sure that complex instantiations of your model still work. You can write a `PropertiesFileWriter` to write a hierarchy to a  file, so you can create an object hierarchy, write it into a file, then read the file into another object hierarchy, and compare the two object hierarchies.

Comment: Do i have to implement the `assertEqual(...)` method for my case?

Comment: Well, `assertEqual()` is a junit method, so you cannot implement it, but it invokes the `equals()` method of your object, so this is actually the one which you have to implement and make sure it works absolutely correctly.

Comment: @T.C. I amended it to make it even a bit more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

To have test very simple and readable you can create something like this

```
@Test
 public void testComposition()
 {
     // given
     Composite expectedObject = getExpectedComposite();

     // when
     Composite createdObject = PropertiesFileParser.parse(file);

     // then
     assertTrue(areCompositesEquals(createdObject, expectedObject));
 }

private Composite getExpectedComposite() {
    Composite composite = new Composite();
    // construct a composite you expect after reading from file

    return composite;
}


private static boolean areCompositesEquals(Composite createdObject,
        Composite expectedObject) {

    // assert...
    // assert...
    // assert...
    // list of asserts here that check the composites are equals (number of children and other condition)

    return true;
}
```

To avoid I/O operations on your disk, you can create mock for your test file.